# Child Records getting skipped because of pagination in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am pulling records from a table which has transactions like below.
And displaying them into UI. And I have pagination in the Grid.
Pagination Detail
Page Size = 5
Page Number = 1

[image: Records]

So here is my sql query

```
select * from Transactions ORDER BY id OFFSET (@PageSize * (@PageNum - 1)) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

And i have some tax calculation for related group of transaction,
for parent transaction 50, i need to calculate the total tax amount from child transactions and show the Total tax in the UI.
eg: ParentTxnNumber = 50, total amount from child transactions is 1500
so total tax will be 1500 * .12 = 180

Now when I query the table with above query with page size 5, i will get records upto rownumber 5, But the problem is i have got the Parent transaction number 51 with 2 child transaction number 103 and 104, but ChildTxnNumber 105 record got skipped because of page size limit.
And because of this Wrong tax amount will be shown in the UI for the ParentTxnNumber 51.

So how do i make sure that i get all the child transaction number for a parentTxnNumber with pagination?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags. Please retag the RDBMS you are using, and only that one. Thanks.

Comment: i am using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not calculating the amount of each parent with the same query?

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [RowNumber] INT
   ,[ParentTxnNumber] INT
   ,[ChildTxnNumber] INT
   ,[Amount] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([RowNumber], [ParentTxnNumber], [ChildTxnNumber], [Amount])
VALUES (1, 50, 101, 500)
      ,(2, 50, 102, 500)
      ,(3, 50, 103, 500)
      ,(4, 51, 104, 510)
      ,(5, 51, 105, 520)
      ,(6, 51, 106, 530)
      ,(7, 52, 107, 500)
      ,(8, 52, 108, 500)
      ,(9, 52, 109, 500)
      ,(10, 52, 110, 500);

DECLARE @PageSize INT = 5
       ,@PageNum INT = 1;

select * 
      ,SUM([Amount]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ParentTxnNumber]) AS [AmountPerPArent]
from @DataSource 
ORDER BY [RowNumber] OFFSET (@PageSize * (@PageNum - 1)) ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

[image]

---

```
SELECT TOP (@PageSize) WITH TIES *
FROM
(
    select *
          ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [ParentTxnNumber]) AS [GroupID]
    from @DataSource 
    ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [ParentTxnNumber])
    OFFSET (@PageSize * (@PageNum - 1)) ROWS --FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
) DS
ORDER BY [GroupID]
```